# How can I make a Soft Outline Shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, outline

Most Outline Shaders or Tutorials found online, are Shaders which are sharp edge-outlines.  Like here:

[image]

Even though a lot of games are already using soft outlines 
 like here:[image]

with a nice gradienty- blurry effect.

Creating a Outline is basically easy (as described here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse)

Also ive seen that wanted effect in 2D:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126

But how do they do it in 3D?

Ive found a useful step-by-step guide here: (https://willweissman.wordpress.com/tutorials/shaders/unity-shaderlab-object-outlines/) . But the first step is already not working. (rendering the 3d object in as pure white to a rendertexture).

Comment: Anytime you're tempted to type the phrase "not working," please immediately backspace it and replace it with a detailed description of the symptoms. There are millions of ways something could not work, including crashing, compile-time or run-time errors, blank screens / output, output that's mirrored, output that flickers or stutters, output that is distorted or discoloured, or any other imaginable way the output could differ from the target.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "blur." That is, the outline is rendered in post processing and blurred before being drawn to the screen. Doing that is going to be hard; I've never managed to write a post processing effect correctly.

Comment: I will not post a complete answer but this link contains a solution that works great http://xroft666.blogspot.bg/2015/07/glow-highlighting-in-unity.html

Answer (score 1):

Sooo after keeping myself busy finding all my mistakes about the tutorial ive made in this:
https://willweissman.wordpress.com/tutorials/shaders/unity-shaderlab-object-outlines/)

I would like to provide a very simple solution- where you dont even have to understand shaders at all.

1. Create a new Camera Gameobject which only Renders things you want in a **RenderTexture**. That Rendertexture will later have the Outline.
   (Set the Culling Mask to a new "Outline" layer.
   Set the Layer of the Objects you want the outline for to the same layer.)
   [image]
   Also create a new RenderTexture and put it inside "TargetTexture" of your camera.
2. Put this script inside that camera gameobject

   ```
   public class OutlineEffect : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public bool Gauss;

       public Material WhiteMaker;
       public Material PostOutline;
       public Material GaussianBlur;

       private Camera cam;

       void Start()
       {
           cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
       }

       void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
       {
           RenderTexture TempRT = new RenderTexture(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 24);
           RenderTexture whiteRT = new RenderTexture(TempRT.width, TempRT.height, TempRT.depth);

           Graphics.Blit(source, whiteRT, WhiteMaker);
           if (Gauss)
           {
               Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, TempRT, PostOutline);
               Graphics.Blit(TempRT, destination, GaussianBlur);
           }
           else
           {
               Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, destination, PostOutline);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. put these shaders inside a material with the same name and put those materials inside that script in step 2.

**WHITEMAKER SHADER**

```
Shader "WhiteMaker" {
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Main Texture 1", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" }
        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            half _SampleTime;

            v2f_img vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f_img o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;
                return o;
            }
            float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR
            {
                // Surface
                float4 main = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                if (main.a == 0)
                {
                    return float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {

                    return float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
                }
                return main;
            }
                ENDCG
            }
    }
}
```

**POST OUTLINE SHADER**

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 

'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Custom/Post Outline"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Main Texture",2D) = "black"{}
    _SceneTex("Scene Texture",2D) = "black"{}
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

        sampler2D _MainTex;
    float4 _MainTex_ST;

    //<SamplerName>_TexelSize is a float2 that says how much screen space a texel occupies.
    float2 _MainTex_TexelSize;

#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#include "UnityCG.cginc"
    struct appdata
    {
        float4 pos : POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    struct v2f
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f vert(appdata v)
    {
        v2f o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.pos);
        o.uv = o.pos.xy / 2 + 0.5;
        return o;
    }


    half frag(v2f i) : COLOR
    {
        //arbitrary number of iterations for now
        int NumberOfIterations = 20;

    //split texel size into smaller words
    float TX_x = _MainTex_TexelSize.x;

    //and a final intensity that increments based on surrounding intensities.
    float ColorIntensityInRadius;

    //for every iteration we need to do horizontally
    for (int k = 0; k<NumberOfIterations; k += 1)
    {
        //increase our output color by the pixels in the area
        ColorIntensityInRadius += tex2D(
            _MainTex,
            i.uv.xy + float2
            (
            (k - NumberOfIterations / 2)*TX_x,
                0
                )
        ).r / NumberOfIterations;
    }

    //output some intensity of teal
    return ColorIntensityInRadius;
    }

        ENDCG

    }
        //end pass    

        GrabPass{}

        Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

        sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _SceneTex;

    float4 _MainTex_ST;


    //we need to declare a sampler2D by the name of "_GrabTexture" that Unity can write to during GrabPass{}
    sampler2D _GrabTexture;

    //<SamplerName>_TexelSize is a float2 that says how much screen space a texel occupies.
    float2 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;

    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"
    struct appdata
    {
        float4 pos : POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };


    struct v2f
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f vert(appdata v)
    {
        v2f o;

        //Despite the fact that we are only drawing a quad to the screen, Unity requires us to multiply vertices by our MVP matrix, presumably to keep things working when inexperienced people try copying code from other shaders.
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.pos);

        //Also, we need to fix the UVs to match our screen space coordinates. There is a Unity define for this that should normally be used.
            o.uv = o.pos.xy / 2 + 0.5;
        o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);

        return o;
    }


    half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
    {
        //arbitrary number of iterations for now
        int NumberOfIterations = 20;

    //split texel size into smaller words
    float TX_y = _GrabTexture_TexelSize.y;

    //and a final intensity that increments based on surrounding intensities.
    half ColorIntensityInRadius = 0;

    //if something already exists underneath the fragment (in the original texture), discard the fragment.
    if (tex2D(_MainTex,i.uv.xy).r>0)
    {
        discard;
        return tex2D(_SceneTex,float2(i.uv.x,1 - i.uv.y));
    }

    //for every iteration we need to do vertically
    for (int j = 0; j<NumberOfIterations; j += 1)
    {
        //increase our output color by the pixels in the area
        ColorIntensityInRadius += tex2D(
            _GrabTexture,
            float2(i.uv.x,1 - i.uv.y) + float2
            (
                0,
                (j - NumberOfIterations / 2)*TX_y
                )
        ).r / NumberOfIterations;
    }


    //this is alpha blending, but we can't use HW blending unless we make a third pass, so this is probably cheaper.
    half4 outcolor = ColorIntensityInRadius*half4(0,1,1,1) * 2 + (1 - ColorIntensityInRadius)*tex2D(_SceneTex,float2(i.uv.x,1 - i.uv.y));
    return outcolor;
    }

        ENDCG

    }
        //end pass    
    }
        //end subshader
}
//end shader
^
[POST OUTLINE SHADER ENDS HERE]
```

**GAUSSIAN BLUR SHADER**

```
Shader "Blur" 
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }

    SubShader
    {
        ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off Fog{ Mode Off }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
            float step_w;
            float step_h;

            struct v2f 
            {
                float4  pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2  uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _MainTex_ST_TexelSize;

            v2f vert(appdata_base v) 
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                step_w = _MainTex_TexelSize.x;
                step_h = _MainTex_TexelSize.y;

                float2 offset[25] = 
                {
                    float2(-step_w*2.0, -step_h*2.0), float2(-step_w, -step_h*2.0),  float2(0.0, -step_h*2.0), float2(step_w, -step_h*2.0), float2(step_w*2.0, -step_h*2.0),
                    float2(-step_w*2.0, -step_h),     float2(-step_w, -step_h),      float2(0.0, -step_h),     float2(step_w, -step_h),     float2(step_w*2.0, -step_h),
                    float2(-step_w*2.0, 0.0),         float2(-step_w, 0.0),          float2(0.0, 0.0),         float2(step_w, 0.0),         float2(step_w*2.0, 0.0),
                    float2(-step_w*2.0, step_h),      float2(-step_w, step_h),       float2(0.0, step_h),      float2(step_w, step_h),      float2(step_w*2.0, step_h),
                    float2(-step_w*2.0, step_h*2.0),  float2(-step_w, step_h*2.0),   float2(0.0, step_h*2.0),  float2(step_w, step_h * 20),   float2(step_w*2.0, step_h*2.0)
                };

                float kernel[25] = 
                {

                    0.003765,    0.015019,    0.023792,    0.015019,    0.003765,
                    0.015019,    0.059912,    0.094907,    0.059912,    0.015019,
                    0.023792,    0.094907,    0.150342,    0.094907,    0.023792,
                    0.015019,    0.059912,    0.094907,    0.059912,    0.015019,
                    0.003765,    0.015019,    0.023792,    0.015019,    0.003765
                };

                float4 sum = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

                for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) 
                {
                    float4 tmp = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + offset[j]);
                    sum += tmp * kernel[j];
                }

                return sum;
            }

        ENDCG //Shader End
        }

    }

}
```

4. create a new "raw image" inside a UI canvas.
   Put the Rendertexture inside that Rawimage. And set the Camera Height and Width as the image Height and Width.
   [image]
5. Its done! You can check the "Gauss" bool true or false- depends on which you prefer. Also you can change the color of the raw image

Comment: How to adjust the size of the outline?